# Overdetermined system of nonlinear equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, machine-learning, nonlinear-system

The following system follows from a maximum likelihood estimation:

$\alpha_1$ = $18c(\beta_2+\beta_3)^{-1}$

$\alpha_2$ = $5c(\beta_1+\beta_3)^{-1}$

$\alpha_3$ = $8c(\beta_1+\beta_2)^{-1}$

$\beta_1$ = $4c(\alpha_2+\alpha_3)^{-1}$

$\beta_2$ = $10c(\alpha_1+\alpha_3)^{-1}$

$\beta_3$ = $17c(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)^{-1}$

with the following constraint:

$\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 = \beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3$

$c$ is a fixed known constant, and the $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s are the unknowns.
Hence, I now have 7 equations for 6 unknowns. I know there should be a solution to this problem, i just don't know how to find it properly.

How do I find this solution, possibly using R or Matlab.

Comment: The equations are not independent. In fact the system isn't overdetermined. By substitution prove that the solution is $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=\beta_1=\beta_2=\beta_3=\sqrt{c/2}$, which is trivial.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake in trying to simplify my problem. Could you look again to the problem now that I edited it.

Comment: Solving the system is possible. But the formulas to write the solutions are very big. This draw to think that another mistake might be in your equations. Please check carefully. I don't edit the solution right now because the task of typing would be too big. I will not edit the solution until the system of equations be correct so that the formulas for the results be of reasonable size.